# Strategy for finding the inverse operator on $C^{1}[0, 1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Assume $T_j, j=1,2,3$ to be a linear operator  $T_j: C^{1}[0, 1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$.

If we're given the form of the operator, i.e.,

$\begin{equation}
T_1x(t) = x'(t)  - x(t),
\end{equation}$

it is easy to check that under the restriction of $x(0)=0$, the inverse operator $T_1^{-1}$ has the form of $\int_{0}^{t} e^{t-s}x(s)ds$.

Alternatively, we can check that for the operator $T_2x(t) = x'(t) + 4x(t)$, the inverse has the form of $T_2^{-1} = \int_{0}^{t} e^{4(s-t)}x(s)ds$ under $x(0)=0$, by following similar logic.

My question: are there any general methods/rules for arriving to the particular expressions of such inverse operators? Obviously, in cases similar to which I've mentioned one can guess the expression with some trial and error, however such approach becomes tedious when dealing with more complicated expressions of the operator $T$ (i.e., $T_3x (t) = (t^2 + 1)x'(t) + 2t^2 x(t)$).

As far as I understand, we need to solve $T^{-1}(Tx) = x$ for $T^{-1}$, however I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no general method. But since all Your examples are differential operators, You would obtain the inverse by solving the differential equation. Unfortunately, it is not always possible.

Comment: For $T_3$ observe that $\frac{e^{2t-2\arctan(t)}}{t^2+1}T_3(x)=(e^{2t-2\arctan(t)}x)'$.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 thanks for your answer, the differential operators are mainly the one's I'm having trouble with, hence the examples. Could you provide a quick example of how would the derivation of the inverse from solving the differential equation look like for any of the simplest cases ($T_1$ or $T_2$)?

Comment: @totoro excellent observation! Thanks!

Comment: For example the equation $T_1x(t)=y(t)$ can be solved by variation of parameters-method. The homogeneous equation $T_1x(t)=x^{'}(t)-x(t)=0$ has $Ce^t$ as the solution. So the variation of parameters gives the equation $C^{'}e^t=y(t)$ with the solution $C=\int y(s)e^{-s}ds$. And so You become the inverse $x(t)=e^t\int y(s)e^{-s}$ which You already know. Unfortunately this method doesn't always work.

Comment: All of them worked by the same technique: [Integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor). For $T_1$, observe that $e^{-t}T_1x=(e^{-t}x)'$. For $T_2$ observe that $e^{4t}T_2x=(e^{4t}x)'$.